# 403 Error being generated from company IP, with no attempts to access site

Tags: http-status-code-403

Currently for a company dedicated hosting server, there are a large amount of 403 errors being generated by the company IP for a specific website, while no one from the company is accessing that site. There are a large number of client sites, as well as a staging site hosted on this server, to which the hosting company locked out the company with the reason "a brute force attack was launched from IP address ... (the company IP)". Is there any way the IP could be used by an outside source, or would there be some software, malware, or general error that could be causing this? I'm far from a security expert, and at a loss while the hosting company is not able to give clear answers other than to offer to disable their "mod_security firewall".

Thanks!

Comment: Well it didn't take long to get trolled with a down vote and no feedback. `<sarcasm>` very productive `</sarcasm>`, by far one of the worst and most off-putting aspects of SO.

Comment: This might belong on a different site @NathanK, eg:Super User Stack. http://superuser.com/

Comment: @mjs thanks, i appreciate the feedback, could you help me understand why not and how to write better questions/determine what is on topic?

Comment: The question itself isn't too bad. Its just not on topic as it has no relavance to programming. Try taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)  to determine what is on topic.

Comment: @mjs thank you. I thought to ask this on security stack exchange, but as i couldnt find any tags relevant to it I assumed it must not be on topic there (though i've never used security before this) so I thought it must be more an SO thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to track on your companies firewall (outbound) what local machines are spamming this external server with requests.

The 403 is just a bi-product of a different problem - the spamming appears to be the root problem. 403 is showing because the request is likely to be malformed and not accepted by the hosted web server.

Comment: I don't disagree at all, that makes sense, let me see if we can access that and I'll let you know where we are at from there. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Shockingly I've discovered we don't have a firewall, nor does the head of IT think getting one is a good idea..

Comment: That is fairly unbelievable! You will struggle to discover the cause of the problem without one. You might be able to install wireshark on everyone's computers and monitor - sounds painful.

Comment: What I did do is go through the raw access logs more thoroughly, and usually the 403 error is incorrect permissions for files I believe, i did see a bunch of get requests on the wp-login page for this site coming from our ip, and surprisingly a few post requests to a russian website. Could this be a sign of a hack attempt? I agree the lack of a firewall is unbelievable and unfortunately I'm powerless in those decisions, and they shut down my suggestion for that right away. We're all on macs, but it looks like wireshark is an option. Worth a shot if i can get permission. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to "steal" an IP when talking about TCP/IP so if the hosting provider detected that it is true.

If you have no firewall where to monitor that and the head of IT thinks does not think that getting one is a good idea..... Go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ and start looking for another.

Comment: :) you might just be right